# .NET replace method from base class in sub class

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.0, vb.net-2010

I have a class:

```
Class ForeignKey_EditField
    Inherits FieldTemplateUserControl
```

The FieldTemplateUserControl class is part of System.Web.DynamicData. In this class there is a method:

```
Protected Sub PopulateListControl(listControl As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl)
     Member of System.Web.DynamicData.FieldTemplateUserControl
```

Which is called from the sub class, how can I replace this method with my own without changing the name. Overloads, shadows etc? What should the signature be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace the method then You need to add the qualifier `overridable` to the base method then the sub class method should be the same but with the qualifier `overrides` instead of `overridable`.

Edit: since override is not an option the alternative is shadows. However shadows is not virtual so the new method will only be called where then compile time type is the subclass or a more specific type. There is no way of forcing calls to the old method to be replaced with the new method where the compile time type is the parent class.